# Assume the file name is given as command line argument. Write a shell script to count lines, characters and words

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I tried solving the problem but I cannot solve the last part where it is given as "Assume the filename is given as command line argument"

Write a shell script which displays the total number of words, characters, lines in a file. Assume the file name is given as command line argument.

```
echo
c=$( wc -c < test.txt)
echo "Number of characters in test.txt is $c"
echo
w=$( wc -w < test.txt)
echo "Number of words in test.txt is $w"
echo
l=$( ec -l < test.txt)
echo "Number of lines in test.txt is $l"
```

I had to pass 2 test cases but I'm only passing one test case as I'm unable to solve the problem assuming the filename as command line argument.

Comment: Hint: the first command line argument passed to your script is `$1`.

Comment: no need to run `wc` three times.  The last one has a typo!

Comment: Check the manual page for `wc`. You'll find you don't need the options. Do a Google search of "how to write a bash script with arguments". It's not hard.

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` as it looks FAR too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Write a script the_script.sh as follows:

```
for F in ${*}
do
   echo
   c=$( wc -c < ${F})
   echo "Number of characters in ${F} is $c"
   echo
   w=$( wc -w < ${F} )
   echo "Number of words in ${F} is $w"
   echo
   l=$( wc -l < ${F})
   echo "Number of lines in ${F} is $l"
done
```

To explain, `${*}` is ll the command line args passed in, and when used with teh `for` loop as above each argument is assin to `$F` in each iteration of the loop.

Then within the loop, refer to `${F}` as the file name.

To run:

```
./the_script.sh text.txt test2.txt ....
```

As others have noted you should avoid running `wc` three times if the files are large, so here is one way to run it just once and process the counts:

```
WC=$( wc ${F} )
l=$( echo $WC | awk '{print $1}' )
w=$( echo $WC | awk '{print $2}' )
c=$( echo $WC | awk '{print $3}' )
```

Comment: You want `"$@"`, not unquoted `$*`, to handle all valid arguments. You also need to quote `$F`.

Answer (score 2):

*This will work*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of characters in $1 `wc -m < $1`"
echo "Number of words in $1 `wc -w < $1`"
echo "Number of lines in $1 `wc -l < $1`"
```

1. ***$1*** : first argument (filename)
2. ***``*** (back quotes) :used to execute commands
3. options:
         -m :count characters
         -w :count words
         -l :count lines

Answer (score 0):

```
for D in ${*}

do

echo

c=$( wc -c < ${D})

echo "Number of Characters in ${D} is $c"

echo

w=$( wc -w < ${D} )

echo "Number of Words in ${D} is $w"

echo

l=$( wc -l < ${D})

echo "Number of lines in ${D} is $l"

done
```

Comment: please fix formatting (as code), and explain your code

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your codes does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also go with this easy format **

```
for F in test.txt
   do 
        echo
        c=$( wc -c < test.txt )
        echo "number in test.txt is $c"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "Number of characters in $1 is $(wc -m < $1)"
 echo "Number of words in $1 is $(wc -w < $1)"
 echo "Number of lines in $1 is $(wc -l < $1)"
```

You need to replace test.txt with $1 while printing.
This will clear both the test cases..

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple solution:

```
wc -c ${*} | awk '{print "Number of characters in " $2 " is " $1}'
wc -w ${*} | awk '{print "Number of words in " $2 " is " $1}' 
wc -l ${*} | awk '{print "Number of lines in "$2 " is " $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it has given in the problem that the file name will be passed a command-line argument. So basically you can print the file name by making use of that command line argument as a variable(It is not test.txt for all test cases).
Here is my code that got accepted in tekstac platform-

```
words=`cat $1 | wc -w`
char=`cat $1 | wc -c`
lines=`cat $1 | wc -l`
echo "Number of characters in $1 is $char"
echo "Number of words in $1 is $words"
echo "Number of lines in $1 is $lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j06LMHBtvZ8uCCFIxM-jTXEHKc9nbAI-b6T4NqV7mBI/edit)echo -e "\n\t\t\tSolution of:-"
echo -e "\nCheck whether the filename accepted as command line
argument exist in the current directory or not"
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo -e "\n\tFile name is not entered"
else
if [ -e $1 ]
then
echo -e "\n\t "$1 "exists"
else
echo -e "\n\t "$1 "does not exist"
fi
fi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
passed=$1  
echo  
echo -n "Number of characters in $passed is "  
wc -c < $passed  
echo   
echo -n "Number of words in $passed is "  
wc -w < $passed  
echo  
echo -n "Number of letters in $passed is "  
wc -l < $passed
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one it works fine. All tests cleared

```
for F in $*

do

  echo

  c=$( wc -c < ${F} )

  echo "Number in characters in ${F} is $c"

  echo

  w=$( wc -w < ${F} )

  echo "Number in words in ${F} is $w"

  echo

  l=$( wc -l < ${F} )

   echo "Number in lines in ${F} is $l"

done
```